# Unable to run a lookup in flow on a public Site page

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm using flow on a [site page](http://fifedom-developer-edition.na1.force.com/guns/Match_setup), and after I enter my Club number and click next I get the below error message. "**unable to parse field as dataType could not be retrieved for the passed field: RawFieldImpl[tableName: Club__c, columnName: Club_Number_shadow__c]"**

I've check the site's user profile and they have full modify all rights on the object.  Then I've check the Field Level Security for Club_Number_shadow__c field and that's editable for all profiles.

When I run the flow within salesforce's flow builder everything works fine.  Just not when I'm running it under the site page.

Comment: Have you turned debug log on the site user and run your flow? Make sure workflow is set to "finest" Debug log may help. That error message is not something I've seen from Flow. Makes me wonder if  it is an apex error. Is the flow only embedded in the VF page? Is there a controller? Extension?

Comment: good suggestion on the debug.  Yes the flow is embedded in the VF page.  No Controller or extension.

Comment: Share the debug logs if you still need help.

Comment: Thanks for the help @SalesforceWizard , here is screen shot of the debug log http://screencast.com/t/COxnnff0zcEO
Here is the screen shot of the flow http://screencast.com/t/03uu5AU5fQ4

Here is the VF page: http://screencast.com/t/lDnxjRD9DIe

Answer (score 0):

OK for those who may come across this later; the issue was around a security settings at the field level.  However this security setting isn't in the normal area, going to the object and setting the FLS for all profiles.

This FLS needs to be done by going to the site -> public access setting -> Field level Security sections and then your object, see [screen shot here](http://screencast.com/t/WwK2q5JzN).

From there you set the FLS and then you should be all set to go.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug! Salesforce has confirmed

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008Xn7AAE

I'm facing the same issue!